# Magento 2: Issue with Product URL rewrite on Single Store Mode

Tags: magento2.3, url-rewrite, product-urls

I'm using Magento 2.3.3 CE. I've enabled the single store mode on a website from ***Stores > Configurations > General > General > Enable single store mode***

After enabling the single store mode, the URL rewrites for the newly created products are not generated automatically.

Already checked the below posts:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5929

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25190

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After so much debugging, I've found an alternative solution for this issue by creating a custom module to generate the URL rewrite while creating/editing a product from Admin.

Create `Vendor/UrlRewriteFix/etc/adminhtml/di.xml` and define the plugin class `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` in the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="vendor_product_after_save" type="Vendor\UrlRewriteFix\Plugin\AfterProductSave" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Now create the product's `afterSave` plugin file in `Vendor/UrlRewriteFix/Plugin/AfterProductSave.php` with the below content.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\UrlRewriteFix\Plugin;

use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlPersistInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;

class AfterProductSave
{
    /**
     * @var ProductUrlRewriteGenerator\Proxy
     */
    private $urlRewriteGenerator;
    /**
     * @var UrlPersistInterface\Proxy
     */
    private $urlPersist;
    /**
     * @var UrlRewrite\Proxy
     */
    private $urlRewrite;
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface\Proxy
     */
    private $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;
    /**
     * @var UrlFinderInterface
     */
    protected $urlFinder;

    /**
     * AfterSave constructor.
     * @param ProductUrlRewriteGenerator\Proxy $urlRewriteGenerator
     * @param UrlPersistInterface\Proxy $urlPersist
     * @param UrlRewrite\Proxy $urlRewrite
     * @param StoreManagerInterface\Proxy $storeManager
     * @param UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductUrlRewriteGenerator\Proxy $urlRewriteGenerator,
        UrlPersistInterface\Proxy $urlPersist,
        UrlRewrite\Proxy $urlRewrite,
        StoreManagerInterface\Proxy $storeManager,
        UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->urlRewriteGenerator = $urlRewriteGenerator;
        $this->urlPersist = $urlPersist;
        $this->urlRewrite = $urlRewrite;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_product
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_product, $result)
    {
        if ($this->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            if (!$this->checkUrlRewrite($_product->getUrlKey())) {
                $stores = $this->storeManager->getStores(false);
                foreach ($stores as $store) {
                    $_product->setStoreId($store->getId());
                    $newUrls = $this->urlRewriteGenerator->generate($_product);
                    try {
                        $this->urlPersist->replace($newUrls);
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $this->log(sprintf('<error>Duplicated url for store ID %d, product %d (%s) - %s Generated URLs:' . PHP_EOL . '%s</error>' . PHP_EOL, $store->getId(), $_product->getId(), $_product->getSku(), $e->getMessage(), implode(PHP_EOL, array_keys($newUrls))));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function isSingleStoreMode()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/single_store_mode/enabled', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }

    /**
     * @param $urlKey
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function checkUrlRewrite($urlKey)
    {
        $filterData = [
            UrlRewrite::REQUEST_PATH => $urlKey.'.html'
        ];
        $rewrite = $this->urlFinder->findOneByData($filterData);
        if (!empty($rewrite)) {
            $type = $rewrite->getEntityType();
            $entityId = $rewrite->getEntityId();
            if ($entityId && $type == 'product') {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Run the deployment commands after enabling the module.

I hope it'll help somebody facing the same issue.